# Declaring String Arrays Causing Issues

Tags: java, android, string, resources

I am trying to declare a string array which I will be working with in my code. I have done this two ways, both of which I thought to be viable options, but one causes my app to crash on load without fail.

**Working Code:**

```
private String[] list = {"apple", "pear"};
```

***Not*** Working Code:

```
Resources res = getResources();
private String[] list = res.getStringArray(R.array.Fruit);
```

The weird thing is, the latter code was copied *directly* from the Android String Resource page. I've made sure that the array (In this case titled `Fruit`) exists, and am now kind of lost.

The **Log Cat** Error I am getting is as follows:

```
02-25 12:38:18.015: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 12:38:18.015: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(605): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ikiar.appname/com.ikiar.appname.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at com.ikiar.appname.Main.<init>(Main.java:24)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-25 12:58:52.284: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT: More Log Cat information, Line of code @ location of crash added**

***@ Location of Crash:***

```
Resources res = getResources();
```

**Solution:**

Moved the location of `Resources res - getResources();` into the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Do you have the xml file named `array` in the `values` folder with a `string-array` named `Fruit`?

Comment: Inside of the `strings.xml` file, I have a `string-array` titled `Fruit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the `string-array` in the `string.xml` file. If you want to use:

```
private String[] list = res.getStringArray(R.array.Fruit);
```

Try to create an `array.xml` file in the `values` folder and there put your `Fruit` array.

Comment: It still crashed after doing that. :/

Comment: @iKiar can you post the exact line where you get the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Stupid question, how can I identify the exact line it crashed at from the error code? (I'm relatively new to Java)

Comment: @iKiar In the logcat where you have the errors you'll have a line `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`, the line below that will be the last point of your code that run just before the exception(on that line at the end you'll have something like `ClassName.java:35`). Check the line with that number in the class.

Comment: I see the ContextWrapper.java line, and do not know where that file is located (not my creation), and I am about to edit the post once more to show where the following line in my main occurs.

Comment: @iKiar Your `Resources res` is null, where exactly do you have this line of code? You can't place it as a field in your class because you don't have the `Context` there(try to move it in the `onCreate()` method) .

Comment: Life saver, I should have come to that myself being such an obvious fix haha, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You get a Nullpointer Exception. I guess "res" is null. What does `System.out.println(res)` say!? When it says "null" then your res is not loaded properly.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer. (Though I realize that action might not be enabled for you yet. :)